# Удалить часть текста записанный в переменную. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Всюду есть такой пример:

```
var str = "awdawd awdaw sss dawdawd"
str.replace(/sss/g, '')
```

Мне надо удалить, когда мое слово( в данном случаи "sss") записано в переменную

```
var x = 'sss'
str.replace(/+'x'+/g, '') // не работает, как тут провести конкатенацию?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var str = "awdawd awdaw sss dawdawd";
var x = 'sss';

// То, что Вам нужно - конструктор RegExp.
// В нём можно проводить конкатенацию строк, как обычно.
// Например: new RegExp('начало' + x + 'конец', 'g')
// (только не забывайте, что второй параметр - флаги - тоже в кавычках)

var rExp = new RegExp(x, "g");

console.log(str.replace(rExp, ''));
```

Comment: Видимо опять сообщения из чата не доходят

Answer (score 1):

Функция `String.prototype.replace()` заменяет именно **строки**, а не переменные, поэтому, код нужно переписать так:

```js
var x = 'sss and some text';
var str = x.replace(/sss/g, '');
console.log(str);
//функцию можно применять прямо на строки, например...
console.log('sss and some text'.replace(/sss/g, ''));
```

Если слова разделены пробелом, можно сделать по-другому:

1. разбиваем строку на массив
2. отфильтровываем ненужную строку
3. склеиваем массив обратно

```js
var str = 'sss dasd ldkagj sss dlgkj ssss';
var arr = str.split(' ').filter(item => item !== 'sss').join(' ');
console.log(arr);
```

Тогда строки типа `ssss` удалены не будут.

Answer (score 0):

Текст должен быть строкой

```js
var x = 'sss';


x.replace(/sss/g, '')
console.log(x)
```

Comment: вопрос исправил, но причем тут ваш ответ? вы суть вопроса не поняли. в строе str длинное значение и в нем нужно найти 'sss' который записан в переменную